# How to add table into query category as a result from a query executed in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to add new tables returned from a `select into` query into the `Queries` category in database panel. VBA automatically adds new tables into the `Tables`.

My code:

```
strquery = "SELECT t1.GSMNo AS GSMNo INTO table_created FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.gsmno = t2.gsmno
WHERE Isnull(t2.gsmno)"
Currentdb.Execute strquery
```

This code creates the new table under `Tables`. How can I add it into the `Queries`?

Comment: pretty sure that you want this createquerydef: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195966.aspx

Comment: From ribbon, simply use Create / Query design / SQL mode and save you `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Access displays your database objects in the navigation pane sorted by their types.

With your query you create a new database object of the type *table*, so it will be listed as a *Table* and not a *Query*.

If you want you can always create a new query containing `SELECT * FROM table_created` that will then be listed as a *Query*.

There is also a way to create custom groups in the navigation pane: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-database-objects-in-the-Navigation-Pane-04f0708d-c7c7-46bc-8c0a-670751f93d36